# Async/Non-blocking Query in sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a long running (simplified) query like:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i in (SELECT * FROM T WHERE ....)
  LOOP
    DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.VALUE);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

When I execute it, it takes hours due to large table and complex condition, and my `sqldeveloper` is basically frozen on that session. I cannot create a new connection, and I have to open a new `sqldeveloper` instance.

Is there anyway to not block it? Like running in the background, but still output to the console/file? I understand I can create SQL script and run from CLI, but I would like to know if there is any solution in `sqldeveloper` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a new private SQL worksheet, which will not share the connection, by clicking the highlighted icon:

[image]

Any query running in the unshared sheet will have no effect on your regular SQL worksheet as it doesnt share the connection with it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While one query is running, simply press ALT + F10 (function key F10) to start another connection, for the same or a different user. The running query will continue to run and will not interfere with your other session.